# beautifulsoup search attributes with namespace

Tags: python, xml

I want to search XML file for xlink:href attribute in all tags. I cannot get it done with beautifulsoup find_all and regular expression. Following is my XML file.

```
<body:document-content>
<style:style style:name="P1" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard">
  <style:text-properties officeooo:paragraph-rsid="00118689"/>
</style:style>

<body:text>
  <text:sequence-decls>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Illustration"/>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Table"/>
  </text:sequence-decls>
  <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is example document</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
  <text:p text:style-name="P1">hello world</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
  <text:p text:style-name="P1">
    <text:a xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="https://example.com">https://example.com</text:a>
  </text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
  <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
</body:text>
</body:document-content>
```

I want to delete the following tag line from the XML file.

```
<text:a xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="https://example.com">https://example.com</text:a>
```

Please suggest how to get this done using beautifulsoup. I have also tried Elementtree. But, it gave lot of namespace issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplistic answer, but it's not clear what you're trying to do, or what variations you might be confronting in your XML. If you don't need to use XPath for more complex operations, the XML in your example suggests that you can just search for the `text:a` element (the only element with the `xlink:href` attribute) -- if it's indeed the `text:a` "line" (element node) that you're looking to get rid of.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.xml') as x: # text.xml is the xml from your post
    doc = BeautifulSoup(x)
    #print(doc.find_all( 'text:a' ))  # see that it gets all text:a elements
    [s.extract() for s in doc('text:a')] # extracts text:a elements
    print(doc)
```